# add vehicle select drop down menu in html

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

I want to add two drop down menus. One for car brand and another for car model.
I have done for car brand, but it is showing only 4 cars which are maruti swift, maruti alto, maruti wagonR. I have a excel file of brand and model which I would like to add to this list.
There are 210 cars in total. I don't want to type it individually as it would take lot of time. Is there a shorter way of doing it ?

This is what I wrote:-

```
<div class="wrap-input100">
                <span class="label-input100">Car Make:</span>
                <!-- <input class="input100" type="text" name="Make" placeholder="Enter Make of Your Car"> -->
                <form action="/action_page.php">
                <select name="cars">
                  <option value="select">select</option>
                  <option value="Maruti,Swift">Maruti,Swift</option>
                  <option value="Maruti,WagonR">Maruti,WagonR</option>
                  <option value="Maruti,Swift">Maruti,Swift Dzire</option>
                  <option value="Maruti,Alto">Maruti,Alto</option>
                </select>
                <span class="focus-input100"></span>
            </div>
```

[image: list of cars i want to add]

Comment: yes you can write a java program using apache poi to read the excel then send the response to the ui and create dropdown using the data in response

Comment: @brk It will be longer, than copy and paste. Pranteek Singh You can copy columns into plain text file and then change it using regexp from your favorite text editor.

Comment: You can add those cars to back-end and get them with ajax call, that will make your code flexible in case you need to add or remove car.

Answer (score 1):

Convert your excel to json from any online tool which will give you array of objects:
(Google "excel to json online" you will find plenty of tools)

You can change the js Object keys of my code as per your json.

[I have created a plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/THbjhdWVPUzKLJgCbMMm?p=preview)

**HTML & Javascript**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>



  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
     <select name="cars" id="cars">
                  </select>
     <script>
        let json = [
    {
        "Brand": "Maruti",
        "Model": "Swift"
    },
    {
        "Brand": "Maruti",
        "Model": "Desire"
    },
    {
        "Brand": "Maruti",
        "Model": "WagonR"
    },
    {
        "Brand": "Maruti",
        "Model": "Ritz"
    },
    {
        "Brand": "Maruti",
        "Model": "Zen"
    },
    {
        "Brand": "Maruti",
        "Model": "Alto"
    }
];
dropDown = document.getElementById('cars') ;
function myFunction(item, index) { 
  console.log(item.Brand,item.Model)
  dropDown.innerHTML = dropDown.innerHTML + "<option value='"+item.Brand + ' ' + item.Model +"'>"+item.Brand +' ' +  item.Model+"</option>"
}

json.forEach(myFunction)


      </script>
  </body>

</html>
```